# How weather-resistant is the Canon EOS 600D?

Tags: canon-60d, weather, canon-600d, rain

I have many friends with Nikon D300s and Canon 7Ds and they say they can handle pretty much anything they throw at them. I know the 600D is **way** less fit for this but I just would like to know, out of curiosity, what conditions that it could maybe withstand. I am only interested in how much the body can take, because I know that the total weather resistance depends a lot on the lens (let's assume I have a EF-L  tele lens attached).

Also possibly, how does it compare to the 60D in terms of weather resistance?

Comment: Please not that not even the EOS 7D cannot handle "everything", you have to be careful. Have a look at this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-weather-resistant-is-the-canon-eos-7d

Comment: I've shot soccer matches in heavy downpours using my Rebel XS (1000D) and T4i (650D) covered with [this simple rain sleeve](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1168171-REG/op_tech_usa_9001022_8_small_rain_sleeve.html) and have had no issues with either after the fact. The worst issue is rain running into the left arm of my raincoat from operating the zoom and my right hand getting hot (even in cold weather) from being under the plastic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically, **not** (weather resistant).  I don't believe any Canon Rebel series is weather sealed or resistant to any appreciable degree more than it looks.

It *may* survive a light spray of water or a little beach sand depending on where it goes, how much, and how long, but its simply not sealed against such things.  If you're going to be shooting in any harsh conditions consider something to protect your camera (trashbags or the like) or a sealed camera + lens.

There's a lot of conflicting information on the net about the 60d sealing, but its not. The official Canon website doesn't state it anywhere in their specs or features.

Comment: Is the 60D a sealed camera?

Comment: There's a lot of conflicting information on the net about that (the 60d sealing), but I don't think so.  The official Canon website doesn't state it anywhere in their specs or features.

Comment: The 60D is not weather-sealed.

Comment: The 60D may not be "weather-sealed", but take a look at this image of the battery compartment - http://a.img-dpreview.com/reviews/CanonEOS60D/images/batt2.jpg

Comment: @rfusca - Just because a company doesn't state the feature on the specs or main website, doesn't mean it doesn't have it.

Comment: @dpollitt - while *technically* true, this is one of those features that if it exists to a significant degree then it gets advertised because its quite desirable for so many users.  But yes, its not a 100% just because its not listed.

Comment: @dpollitt:  If a camera is weather sealed it WILL be mentioned in all marketing literature.  It's a valuable feature to a lot of people and they would not leave that off.  It doesn't matter if the battery compartment is sealed, all it takes is a single dial or port (like the cable release port) that is NOT sealed and water will be inside.

Comment: I'm just saying, its not cut and dry. Mfgs specs don't tell every detail, and the 60D does have some degree of sealing.

Answer (score 2):

The Rebel series might not be weather as rfusca commented but it is not worth the risk in finding out.  I have recently purchased 600D and do not intend to take it out in the rain etc to prove the weather resistance.  Previously, I owned a 350D which still worked fine after it had a dip in the sea (I went in first), the 600D will have better resistance and build to this.  If you are wanting to take your camera into adverse weather conditions then I would make sure it is protected and you have insurance to cover anything that might happen.

Comment: What makes you think "the 600D will have better resistance and build to this" ?

Comment: @rfusca just evolution. Even low end models improve. Same as the xxD lines got better over time and the xD lines did as well. 7D > 5D MK II > 5D for example.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a Canon 600d under heavy snow and it gets wet but it not damaged;
by the way I used a 18-200 EF-S zoom lens.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to just go out and test my Rebel in the cold. No rain or snow: just the cold. I spent an hour shooting at minus 15 Celsius with no other problems besides numb fingers.

I'll let you know how it goes when I'll try it at minus 40!

Comment: Careful! It's not the cold that will do it in: it's the sudden transition back to a warm, relatively wet environment that causes condensation which can damage your camera and lens.  See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5664/what-should-i-consider-when-using-dslrs-in-cold-weather

Answer (score 2):

We have just been photographing for 2 hours in the rain and 2 different 600D cameras have not lasted the weather conditions. It wasn't heavy rain but more of a drizzle so I wouldn't risk it!

Answer (score 1):

I do not own a 600D but I owned a 300D and it performed in inclement weather with a covering such as a trash bag.

It was able to take getting wet, not of being submerged. 
Also it handled extreme cold and heat very well.

My only issue was condensation from going to hot to cold or vice versa. I was very careful to give the the camera and the lenses enough time  to  adjust to the differences in temperature so to minimize the condensation.

Answer (score 1):

No, the 600D cannot handle everything.

But for the 7D: watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCT-YMgjm9k&list=UUuw8B6Uv0cMWtV5vbNpeH_A&index=3&feature=plcp) (not for the faint of heart!): after hitting it with a car, dropping it down some steps on a wheelchair, freezing it, soaking it and setting fire to it - it still works! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had it out in the rain for an hour this afternoon in light to moderate rainfall. So far it has worked quite well. Should I have any problems in the future, I'll come back here and post it.