# How weather-proof is a Nikon D5300?

Tags: weather-sealing, nikon-d5300

A few days back, I went for a riverside shoot with my Nikon D5300. Unfortunately, moderate rain soon started. I noticed a few photographers, probably with professional grade cameras, were daring enough to shoot the landscape in such weather. The scenic beauty around at that moment was mesmerizing, but I missed capturing any shots, fearing that a single droplet of water would burn out my DSLR. Before trying out taking pictures in rainy condition with my Nikon D5300, I need to know how weather-proof it is. Any suggestions/authentic information is appreciated.

Comment: Why not using a rain cover or a simple homemade plastic protection ?

Comment: Arguably not a duplicate, but given that they're both mid-grade DSLRs I think this is a valid question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/is-the-canon-60d-weather-proof

Answer (score 2):

The D5300 is an entry-level DSLR and is not weatherproof at all. As most cameras, it will handle a few drops of water or snow but you should not let it get wet.

Weatherproof DSLRs and mirrorless exist and they will be able to stand up to strong rain without issues as long as a weatherproof lens is also attached. All camera manufacturers except Pentax/Ricoh reserve such features of higher-end models and pricier lenses, so if you want to get a weather-sealed DSLR and lens for a low cost, you will have to switch systems.

There are things called rain-covers which are basically ponchos for a camera which you can buy to use your D5300 in the rain. Its a little cumbersome to work with and you have to be careful because it is not a sealed bag, but can do for occasional rain. These cost $50-$100 the last time I checked. There different sizes are to accommodate different lenses.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is or not but I took my D5300 up Snowdon while it was raining and hailing, camera got drenched but it is still in good condition

Comment: I'd vote for cameras not being too prone to water too (I tried my cameras which were not proof) but this still is more of a luck if camera survives soaking. Your answer does not seem to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The most authentic information available for the D5300 is the official manual. Here is the link:

http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/BTcII00t9KUv024jW9c13oRqeg68/D5300VRRM_(En)02.pdf

Specifically, in the "Caring for the Camera" section, there are several important indicators as to how weatherproof your camera really is, for example:

> **Keep dry :** This product is not waterproof, and may malfunction if immersed in water or exposed to high levels of humidity. Rusting of
>   the internal mechanism can cause irreparable damage.
>
> **Avoid sudden changes in temperature :** Sudden changes in temperature, such as those that occur when entering or leaving a
>   heated building on a cold day,can cause condensation inside the
>   device. To prevent condensation, place the device in a carrying case
>   or plastic bag before exposing it to sudden changes in temperature.
>
> **Keep away from strong magnetic fields :** Do not use or store this device in the vicinity of equipment that generates strong
>   electromagnetic radiation or magnetic fields. Strong static charges or
>   the magnetic fields produced by equipment such as radio transmitters
>   could interfere with the  monitor, damage data stored on the memory
>   card, or affect the product’s internal circuitry.
>
> **Do not leave the lens pointed at the sun :** Do not leave the lens pointed at the sun or other strong light source for an extended
>   period. Intense light may cause the image sensor to deteriorate or
>   produce a white blur effect in photographs.

Further information is provided as well, including caring for the battery, so I suggest you read through it to get a better understanding of the weather capability of your camera.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Frost bite]

Above, you see frost on my camera. It is okay to use your camera in moderate rain and just dry off the camera well before the next use.

Comment: The camera might be okay - but how hard was it to get that ball-lock to move at those temps?!