# What should I look for when shopping for a DSLR?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr

I am considering buying a new DSLR camera. What differentiates the different options? What specific features should I be looking for?

Comment: You might also be interested in this question about features to look for: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/things-to-look-for-in-my-first-slr-camera