# Best Camera in a range of 13-16k INR

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

I would like to buy a new camera. Maximum I hope to use is around 15-16k INR ($240 - $300 USD). Can anyone suggest me some good options in that range. :)

It will be a great help. I wish to give it as a present. He is not a beginner, I mean, he is almost good at photography. So please keep that in mind too. :)

Comment: This question is very vague at the moment, so it's going to be difficult for anybody to answer, without you narrowing down the field of what you're looking for, types of photos, types of camera that you're interested in.  There are lots of related questions on the site that might help to narrow the field, for example: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your price range I would suggest something like the Canon S90, S95 or S100. It is an affordable compact camera with all the features and controls you would expect in a much larger SLR. You can [read a review here](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/canon_powershot_s90_review/). I have had one myself for a few years now and love it. I also have a much larger Nikon SLR but 95% of the time I use the Canon. I would recommend it without reservation.

I'm sure other people will have a very different opinion - I look forward to reading them with interest!