# best camera between nikon 3200 and canon 600D for product photography and landscape photography?

Tags: dslr, landscape, product-photography

I am about to buy either nikon 3200 or canon 600D .

I will be using for mainly  product photography and landscape photography .

I checked both in the showroom and saw that nikon 3200 displayed red color shirt as orange on the display while 600D had true color.

I saw less depth in nikon,it was not as good as canon but canon had more noise when zoomed . I know I can remove noise in lightroom but This will be my first buy .

Also canon flashed 4 times quickly while nikon took time .There was an argument about the sensor of canon being better than nikon for the above models but few websites say otherwise .Also canon had a motor which had auto adjust modes .I have a mixed feeling about it.

I checked may websites and I am a beginner and would like to content with the product I would purchase .

I will be investing a lot of money .

SO please tell me which one would be good for mainly  product photography and landscape photography. Also among the two which has the best image quality?

Comment: The comparisons you've done in the showroom are not good ways to evaluate the differences between these cameras, and the conclusions you've drawn by looking at the LCD screen are not particularly valid. Either of these cameras is perfectly fine. Based on the way you are evaluating, though, I suspect you will end up finding fault with whatever you buy. Try to reverse how you are looking. Instead of trying to find and magnify faults, trust that both (like all current DSLRs) are excellent machines, and focus on how you can learn to work with them better.

Comment: SO I could go for either of them in the start  and the quality of the image will be more or less the same ? And it the art of photography I should be looking at and not the hardware at this particular moment right ?

Comment: Yes. At a high level, the image quality is fundamentally the same. (A solid "A" in both cases, as with all current DSLR and mirrorless cameras at this price point.) Maybe try [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

Comment: I checked into all that thanks for your time. Can I go with canon 600D then? Thats what looked good so far though the price is little higher that nikon 3200 . Just wanted a second word before the purchse thats it .Thanks again Sir.

Comment: Sure. If you like that one, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it. Like all cameras, it has its quirks, but nothing is perfect for all people. Best to get a camera in hand and start shooting!

Comment: The best camera is the one you actually use. Good ways to choose: brand friends have or fits in your hand better. Bad ways to choose: costs more, pros use it, camera blog says some spec is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both of the models you are considering will do fine for your intended purposes.** Regardless of what you buy, there will always be a better camera and lens than the one you have. Even if there isn't one now, there will be one soon! *The most important ingredient in a photograph is the skill and experience of the photographer.* Even when it comes to hardware, the camera body is, more often than not, *not* the most important piece of the puzzle. With product photography the quality of light illuminating the subject and how it is modified is the primary hardware concern. With landscape photography the most critical aspect in terms of hardware is normally lens performance.

The most significant difference between the two is in the sensors. The D3200 has higher resolution (24.2MO vs. 18MP). This can be an advantage at times as it gives you a little more room to produce very large prints and also to crop images. It also means larger file sizes per image which may or may not be an issue for you. The higher resolution comes at a price, though. Since the sensors are roughly the same size the pixels are packed in tighter on the D3200. This means each individual pixel is slightly smaller than the pixels on the 600D. Pixel size affects things like the Diffraction Limited Aperture, light sensitivity, and image noise. Sensitivity and noise are especially important at higher ISO. In general most reviewers who have compared the two feel the 600D controls noise better than the D3200 at ISO 800 and above. There are other, more technical reviews that give the nod to the D3200 (most notably DxO Mark, which can be considered controversial by some.)

Comparing the output of either camera in the camera store is not a good way to decide this. Perhaps the difference you see is related more to the particular settings of each camera at the time, and it is certainly concerned with the quality of each camera's preview screen as much as it is with the quality of the actual image stored on the memory card. Would you rather have the image that looks best on a calibrated monitor or the one that looks best on the back of the camera? Screens on the back of cameras are known for not being very accurate in terms of color, especially under lighting like you find in most retail establishments.

If your images are going to be viewed primarily over the internet, then either camera has more than enough image quality to produce excellent photos. Choose one and start learning how to use it!

Comment: For most use, the difference between 24mpix and 18mpix is esoteric. In order for there to be a meaningful difference even in large prints and for cropping, the image will have to be taken very carefully, with a nice lens and probably using a tripod. Like the pixel-peeping high ISO comparisons, I _really_ don't think this should be thrown at a beginner as a deciding factor.

Comment: Where does this answer make resolution the *deciding factor*? I'm sure the OP is already well aware of the respective resolutions. *I think it is appropriate to point out that the difference in resolution creates subtle differences that work both for and against **both** cameras.* If anything, the answer distinguishes that more MP doesn't always mean "better".