# Which DSLR camera to choose for semi-pro use?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr

I want to buy a DSLR for casual photography and sometimes professional use. Professional use would include shooting architecture (working with wide angle lenses) and events (low-light conditions). Casual use would include shooting almost everything in daily life (mostly landscapes during my travel). I want to buy a DSLR that I don't quickly outgrow and that is value for money too. Preferred brands are Canon and Nikon only, and budget is up to about 750 USD.

Comment: What camera did you previously own? What is your experience level with SLR cameras?

Comment: Take a look at [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr) and the series of questions linked from that.

Answer (score 3):

At your price point, you are looking at entry level units, not semi-professional unless you look at older, non-current, used models.  Value wise, pretty much any camera is priced based on the value and you get what you pay for.  Generally, semi-pro or prosumer cameras from Nikon and Canon are in the $1500 to $2500 range.

The general rule of thumb for canon is that the more digits the model has, the less professional it is.  3 digit models are entry level, 2 digit models are mid to higher end consumer and single digit are professional or true prosumer bodies.