# Nikon D750 or D5300 for YouTube Videos and macro/landscape photography?

Tags: dslr

I'm a beginner with DSLRs and it would be my first purchase so I don't want to waste my money. I've done some research and have found these both cameras to be good. The only problem is that which one should I buy? My uses would be just to record 1080p videos for YouTube and to capture stunning images of Langscape and Macros.
D750 is great but it cost almost twice the rate of D5300, will that would be a better option to go with? or should I simply go with D5300?

In case there are other better and cheaper options available then do let me know. And do you know any DSLR which can record 4K (under 1 Lakh INR = 1700 USD)

Thanks again.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: The cameras you mentioned will do what you want perfectly adequately so it's impossible to answer your question. When writing a question here you need to think about how it might help other visitors and because your question is asking for a recommendation of equipment which will be obsolete in X amount of years it doesn't fit the criteria.

Comment: D750 + lens will cost far more than twice what a D5300 + lens will cost. At least 3x more, more likely 4x more.

Comment: I think this question could be worthwhile if it were rewritten as "does a beginner need a full frame camera" or something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

Answer (score 2):

Let me throw out my beginner answer: if you don't know why you need the much more expensive thing, you don't need it. A D5300 is a great choice for a beginner.