# list of camera for wedding photography?

Tags: wedding, outdoor

How to make background blurred  in Nikon camera,please give me full details?

Comment: Nikhil, that edit doesn't make the question more on topic at all. You may want to start with 
[What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first “serious” camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/what-do-i-need-to-consider-to-choose-between-dslr-mirrorless-or-a-compact-as-m) and/or 
[What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best would probably be full-frame DSLR camera (for good photos in low light conditions), and you need different focal lenghts, from 135 mm (35 mm equivalent) for portrait to wide angle (16-20 mm) for spontaneous reportage photos of the group. It is good to have USM or STM for fast focus. And you will need at least one external flash.