# Amateur photographer unsure what camera to buy; would also like the ability to take high quality videos

Tags: camera-recommendation, amateur

I am an amateur photographer and filmmaker, it is now time to buy my own camera. I have had my eye on the Canon 760D but I was wondering if there were more models I could consider without spending so much money. A dSLR is definitely the main option. If I could get some advice on what to look for and what to get, that would be great.

Comment: Possibly see: [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first “serious” camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987); and [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876). Video aspects of a camera are better asked on [video.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/). Why is a dSLR "definitely the main option" if you don't want to spend so much money?

Comment: All of the current cameras on the market are pretty good and there isn't much difference between the different manufacturers' entry level offerings. Although it could change in the near future with new product introductions, Nikon has a *slight* edge in still image quality and Canon has an edge in video autofocus considerations. The video AF difference gets larger if you move up to a model with Dual Pixel AF for shooting video. You pay your money and you make your choice.

Answer (score 0):

> 760D but I was wondering if there were more models I could consider

Ok the question you SHOULD ask yourself is:

What do you want to consider? and some aditional questions. Why am I considering that?

For example, what did you find usefull on the borowed cameras you used?

- ISO, Low noise?
- Audible nouse?
- Focus system?
- Internal Color gradings and settings?
- FPS? 30, 60?
- Internal image stabilization?

The more clear are you responding to this questions the more clear the options will be.

You are not answering either lenses. On film they are more important than the body.