# Is a Canon T5 a good starting DSLR camera as a Pixel XL owner?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, dslr, photography-basics

This is probably a bit of a silly question, but I would rather ask now before investing hundreds in a new DSLR camera so that I don't regret it later.

In short, I currently have a Pixel XL which I use for all of my photography (as a hobby). The Pixel XL is probably by far the best phone camera I have used, but it is only a phone camera.

Still, phone camera or not, the phone itself is a $900 piece of equipment, and it makes me wonder if investing in a ~$380 DSLR is still going to be a major "step up" for my first true DSLR camera.

So is this still a good choice, or should I save up and invest in something a bit better? If the latter, any recommendations (again, for someone who has never used a true DSLR camera before)?

Comment: Derp. That's not necessarily the dupe I meant to link to. Possible duplicate of: [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first “serious” camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67987/11924)

Comment: Why do you want a DSLR? Why do you think it will better than the phone? What sort of pictures will you be taking?

Answer (score 0):

Try researching the Canon Rebel SL1. It has features that the T5 wasn't made to match. (I.E Mic Jack, Touch screen). Although it is an older camera, you may want to consider it over the T5.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you go with one of the "i" series, like the T5i. For the money you get much more. As for your question "is this still a good choice" - Yes. You'll be able to do everything you want as a beginner with something like a T5i while you're learning the basics of DSLR's.

Also it's not going to lose a significant amount of value over the next two years, so even if you do upgrade later it wouldn't be a big hit.

I started with a T3i before I upgraded to a pro body, but I still use the T3i for some things.