# Nikon B700 bridge camera vs Canon 1300D DSLR for beginner?

Tags: dslr, comparison, bridge-camera

I have been doing photography with my mobile camera. I want to step up to the next level. I am confused between Nikon B700 (bridge camera) which has really good features and 60x zoom and Canon 1300d (DSLR). I want to cover most types of photography.

Comment: I am tight on my budget and currently can spend around INR 20000-25000

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question. But...

> I want to do all type of photography.

There is **no camera** that can do all types of photography!

I have a mirrorless camera, and I like buying good lenses for it. But when I go running, I use a cheap, second-hand Sony DSC-W310... can't bother with the weight of my main camera.

Do you need a Nikon B700 with its 60x zoom? Hobby birdwatchers like superzoom cameras. They want to "catch" birds, not primarily good images. When I had the Canon G3X (it's a fine camera for many purposes), I found I rarely used its wide zoom.

I would rather invest in a camera with less zoom, but a larger sensor size. The B700 has a 1/2.3" sensor. That's basically a mobile phone camera with a good lens in front of it. If you can afford it, select a camera with a 1" sensor.

Otherwise, read [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first "serious" camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/what-do-i-need-to-consider-to-choose-between-dslr-mirrorless-or-a-compact-as-m) :)