# I WANT TO GET INTO FILM

Tags: equipment-recommendation, photo-editing, camera-recommendation

i’m trying to get into film/photography i think just photography right now and then move over to film. anyways i need a camera obviously but i have no idea where to even start. so could someone please send me some camera recommendations?
i have another question too! i would like to start editing these pictures but again there’s so many things to choose from i have no idea which would be best so what should i download?? i have a macbook pro

Comment: So which is it - digital or film? Black and white or color? Developing at home or using a lab? Are you taking a class? What's your instructor recommend? Have you searched google? This site alone has quite a few posts on first cameras for beginners...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a dupe of the above. Please read it. If you have questions after reading it, feel free to post another question. Also, shooting and editing are very, very different beasts. Please keep your questions to the absolute smallest subject, and ask multiple questions - instead of starting a thread with multiple questions in it. Thanks!

Comment: Also see [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first "serious" camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987/what-do-i-need-to-consider-to-choose-between-dslr-mirrorless-or-a-compact-as-m)

Comment: I think "film" in this context is "video", not "non-digital photography".

Comment: Please clarify if it's "film" as in "movie" or "film" as in "stills photography using film not digital".

Answer (score 3):

Emylee,  i think you are using the word "film" to refer to video. Film means several things. The word film in still photography and on this stack exchange refers to the physical product of [photographic film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_film).

Before digital cameras,  photos were captured on film. ( and before that, [glass plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_plate) )

Before video tape movies were recorded on photographic film. That is why some old timers like me refer to movies as a [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film).

I.E. lets go catch a film at the theater or i would like to make a film.

I would recommend getting a camera that has full manual control, take a class at school or apprentice with  local photographer and learn to use your camera with manual settings so you will have a solid understanding of how a camera works and how light behaves and how to capture it.

Photography is the art of capturing light and the best photographers understand light, how to see it, how cameras see it and record it, how to manipulate light for the best photos or how to express your artistic vision.