# Which camera should I buy as a beginner?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera

I'm new to photography. In the past I took photos using cellphones. Cellphones are not professional cameras (are they?), so I want to buy a professional one. Because I have no idea what makes a good camera, I did some search on Google, but only to find huge variance in their price. For example these are 3 of the Google search results:

- Panasonic $448
- Nikon $1400
- Canon $2900

I didn't search Made-in-Japan products specifically, but most of the results are Japanese products. However their prices still vary a lot. The cheapest one is $400 but expensive ones can go thousands of dollars. What makes the difference? I'm not asking for recommendation of a specific product, but I would like to have some tips about choosing a good camera that would not unduly restrict my skills. Still I'm wondering if all good cameras are made in Japan?

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you please define the criterias which are important to you?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately this is exactly the kind of question that this site is not for, per https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask it is not for "open-ended purchase recommendations" nor "which camera/brand is the best". I expect that it will soon be closed. But I would advise researching the difference between interchangeable-lens cameras and non-interchangeable-lens cameras, between mirrorless and DSLR cameras, and between sensor sizes. Those are good places to start if you know nothing at all yet.

Comment: Moderator note: I have removed the links from this question because they are monetised links to install ad blockers. **Please do not do that anywhere on Stack Exchange**.

Comment: As @wonderbear has noted, this question isn't a good fit in its current form so I've closed it pointing to two of our canonical "first camera" questions. I will pick up on one thing though - "Cellphones are not professional cameras (are they?), so I want to buy a professional one.": there are no professional cameras, only professional photographers. Gear will not make you a better photographer.

Comment: Don't focus too much on where a camera brand comes from. It doesn't matter if you are buying a camera, a bicycle, or a car, all the manufacturers offer different products at different price points, with increasingly appealing/useful feature sets. (Mostly.)

Comment: Additionally, the 3 cameras you link to (now redacted) are in pretty different categories - one bridge camera, one APS-C DSLR and one full-frame mirrorless camera. You need to understand the categories of cameras, and the fact that some cameras have interchangeable lenses. You also need to have a reasonably clear idea of _why_ you want to buy a camera, what you will use it for. You should accept that throwing money at gear is not the way to improve your photography - IMO, this path almost never works, and you end up dissatisfied, and with an expensive piece of camera kit that never gets used.

Comment: Cameras are tools. Which tool is most useful depends upon what one wishes to use a tool to do. This question reads almost like, "Which tool should I buy? A crosscut saw, a #2 Phillips head screwdriver, or a 24 oz. framing hammer?" Or maybe, "Which vehicle should I buy? A Chevrolet Corvette sports car, a Mercedes Sprinter delivery van, or a Prevost Motor Coach?" The answer all depends upon what task you need to perform, doesn't it?

Comment: See also: [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first "serious" camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987)