# What are the primary differences between Canon 600D and 700D?

Tags: canon, canon-600d, canon-700d

I'm planning to buy a new SLR Camera . I'm confused between the Canon 600D and 700D. What are the primary differences?

Comment: This is getting downvotes because it seems like something you could easily find at any camera review site. Is there something in particular you are confused about?

Comment: You may also want to see 
[What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2876/1943)

Answer (score 2):

There are not a whole lot of differences between the two models. They are based on the same sensor and offer a lot of the same features, controls, and options. They both use the same battery and are almost identical in terms of size and weight.

Here are the most noticeable differences:

- The 700D uses the newer, more powerful DiGiC 5 processor, the 600D uses a DiGiC 4 processor.
- **The 600D was introduced in early 2011.** It was replaced about 15 months later by the 650D in the spring of 2012, and then a year after that **the 700D replaced the 650D in 2013**. The 700D was near identical to the 650D other than a newer grip material. The 750D replaced the 700D in early 2015.
- Both models have 9 auto focus points, but **only the center point of the 600D is a cross type point sensitive at f/5.6** with additional sensitivity when using a lens f/2.8 or wider. **All 9 of the auto focus points on the 700D are cross type and sensitive at f/5.6**, with the center point also more sensitive when using an f/2.8 or wider lens.
- The rear LCD on the 700D includes touchscreen capability, the rear LCD on the 600D does not.
- Both models allow for in-camera peripheral illumination correction, but only the 700D also allows for in-camera correction of chromatic aberration. In both cases the proper lens correction profile for the lens used must be loaded to the camera. Some lens profiles are loaded by default in the factory, others may be added using the *EOS Utility* software included with all new Canon DSLRs.
- The 600D is rated at 3.7 frames per second and has a shutter lag of 90 milliseconds. The 700D is rated at a faster 5.0 fps and a shorter shutter lag of 75 ms. This is mostly a result of the faster DiGiC 5 processor in the 700D compared to the DiGiC 4 processor in the 600D.
- There are slight differences in the automatic scene modes available between the two.
- When using the Live View feature to shoot stills or movies, the rear LCD screen refreshes at 30 frames per second on the 600D and 60 frames per second on the 700D. However, the movie recording sizes and frame rate options available are identical between the two models.
- The 700D includes the new Hybrid CMOS AF when shooting or recording video in Live View. The 600D does not. This allows faster and smoother focusing in Live View, which is particularly important when recording video with continuous autofocus. The benefit of the Hybrid CMOS AF will be most apparent when the 700D is coupled with an STM lens.
- The 700D allows manually setting the audio recording level or letting the camera set it automatically. The 600D sets the audio level automatically with no manual option.
- The 700D can take advantage of higher performance UHS-1 SDXC cards. The 600D can not. Both are compatible with SD/SDHC/SDXC cards. The 700D will also create a new file and continue to record if a movie file reaches 4GB in size. The 600D must be manually restarted when the 4GB limit is reached.

Comment: Very important too : one has a name containing a "7", the other doesn't.

Comment: Why is the "7" in the model name very important?

Comment: It's just a joke as the OP has probably not spent much time looking for data :)