# Does Fujifilm make DSLR cameras anymore?

Tags: dslr, fujifilm

I've been trying to find a Fujifilm DSLR camera online but it seems like all of them have been discontinued.

Edit: Why do I want a Fujifilm camera? They are well-designed cameras that shoot high quality photos, according to their reviews.

Why do I want a DSLR? I've compared an EVF on a mirrorless camera (Sony a6000) to the viewfinder on a friend's DSLR (Canon EOS Rebel) side by side. I couldn't see as much detail through the EVF. I realize it's not a controlled experiment, but that's all the first-hand evidence I have to go on right now.

Comment: I've answered the question as asked, but you might get more useful information if you explain *why* you want a Fujifilm SLR.

Comment: The Fuji X-Pro models have hybrid viewfinders that are both optical *and* electronic and they're not dSLRs, either.

Comment: Some EVFs are better than others. The A6000 EVF is only 1.4 megapixels, many newer mirrorless cameras are 2.3 megapixels. Did you try adjusting the dioptre wheel?

Comment: @vclaw, it seemed to have more to do with color space resolution than spatial resolution. It wasn't out of focus in the EVF so adjusting the diopter wheel probably wouldn't have helped.

Comment: Modern EVFs can, in many cases, be better than optical viewfinders. They also can provide functionality not available in an optical viewfinder like zebra stripes and magnification to aid manual focusing. You should check out the lates Fujifilm cameras before coming to any conclusions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the last Fujifilm SLR was the [Finepix IS Pro](https://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/slrs/fuji_ispro), released in 2007. Fujifilm's interchangable lens cameras these days are the mirrorless X system and the medium format GFX system.

Comment: Worth noting that the X-T* series cameras have an SLR-like form factor.

Comment: @mattdm, as OP explicitly says he doesn't want a mirrorless, I think it's irrelevant.

Comment: @walther Well, before the edit, it wasn't clear what exactly the OP didn't want from a mirrorless. Plus, ideally, answers should serve a wider audience than just the one poster.

Answer (score 3):

That's a legit question. But as @PhilipKendall wrote in answer, Fujifilm stopped their DSLR production, so last one is pretty old now, meaning average image quality, high ISO performance, small system of lenses.

Sensor and computer quality changed a lot since 2007, and cheapest modern DSLR cameras will likely outperform best one Fuji ever made. That is not only number of megapixels, but performance in low light, automatic color balance, size and quality of rear LCD, autofocus speed and precision (Fuji lacks face recognition for example) and other characteristics.

Today you can buy much better gear from Nikon/Canon if you need DSLR. So you might look at [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

PS: I think your Q got downvotes because of poor research. You should be able to look at comparison and reviews of modern cameras against Fuji's online.