# Budget DSLR for a beginner

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

I own a Fujifilm s7000 bridge camera. Now I would like to buy a budget DSLR to follow 
[The Digital Photography Book, Part 5: Photo Recipes](http://amzn.eu/hEwGa8m). Most of  the recipes use  70–200mm f/ 2.8 lens. I'm thinking about buying a Canon 10D; would that camera be a good choice for a beginner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

Comment: Is there a reason you are looking at that particular model?

Comment: Thank you. It's mainly price. I need minimum to follow the recipes

Answer (score 3):

The Canon 10D was a ground-breaking consumer DSLR 15 years ago. It will certainly meet the minimums you might need to learn photography, but because it is so old, many people would find it frustrating. It is very slow by modern standards, and doesn't have many of the conveniences people expect from cameras today.

That said, your current S7000 camera is also from that era, so... maybe you won't be so for off. However, I think you'll *probably* be better off looking for a deal on a camera at least a decade newer.

In an earlier version of your question, you note that you're looking to spend under £150. Note that you won't be getting a 70-200mm f/2.8 lens for that price on *any* camera body.

Comment: wow  so is there any budget option to lear photography? Should I go for a newer bridge camera instead?

Comment: @nish1013 It's an expensive hobby, I'm afraid. Personally, I'm not a fan of "bridge" cameras, but they do suit some people and purposes. I'd suggest looking for one of the interchangeable-lens options from [dpreview's 2017 budget camera list](https://www.dpreview.com/reviews/2017-buying-guide-best-cameras-under-500) — or find that list from a year or two ago and look for used bargains, but don't go more than a few years back.