# Does just Canon's color science make it worthy to buy?

Tags: canon, color

Whenever Canon is compared to any other brands, their color science becomes part of the comparison and most photographers, even Nikon users, admit that Canon has good colors.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Samia. This question doesn't really have an answer (though I've tried). We close questions on this site that are primarily opinion based and have no objective answer. If you'd like to learn more about the color science, please ask. But, asking if **that aspect** is worth a purchase gets into the non-objective opinion territory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is just canon colour science make it worthy to buy?

**Short Answer**: No.

**Longer Answer**: SLR's have differentiated themselves from one another since the beginning. Canon, Nikon, Pentax, Fuji, Olympus...all the brands *have* to have some differentiating factors in order to have a competitive edge in the market.

At this point in time, each brand offers multiple differentiating factors from the others. No single factor, IMO, is worth a purchase decision. Instead, you should be looking at all of the things that are important *to you* and then match those up with a camera system that will match.

---

Addendum: If you are not sure of all of the factors that you are looking for in a camera, then you are probably very new to photography. This is not a good time to sink tons of money into a system. If possible, rent before you buy. If that isn't possible, do a ton of research. We've got a lot of good questions here like: [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

Answer (score 0):

I agree short answer is no. I just finished watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMfCDujQywY and reading this: https://www.pdnonline.com/gear/cameras/the-best-cameras-for-color-reproduction-ranked/#

I never quite got why people spent any time on this but now I get why I never cared (and neither should you:-). If you shoot RAW you are in complete control of the colour. When you watch the video check out the portion where Tony white balanced all his test images to the same sample and none came out on top as a favourite.

And we should all be shooting RAW :-)

Comment: The charts showing Delta E of the different cameras is highly misleading. It is meaningful only for reproduction work, not taking pictures. Reproduction work ideally constructs a replica of what is being imaged. These pictures look washed out and unattractive because people prefer more saturation, contrast, and lighter photos than what was actually photographed.  Reproduction captures are called "Scene Referred" while normally captured images intended for print are called "Output Referred." The alterations are made to produce pleasing photos, not accurate ones.