# Canon 77D or 80D

Tags: canon, canon-80d

I am new to DSLR. When I am searching for one with features and price range I found 77D and 80D. I have seen the differences in technical specifications in both the cameras from a lot of sources but what I didn't get is how it makes difference in action. And I also came across something like lens is more important than body (not sure how much this is true). Every difference makes me more confuse in picking the right one.

I would like to be able click a running squirrel or a flying sparrow. As I didn't found this in anywhere can anyone suggest which one of these (or none of these) have the ability for that?

Can I get a clear picture of a small bird (assuming it is in the range for 18-135mm lens and it is flying around a flower) using 77D with 1/4000 shutter speed? or only 80D can do it?

What 80D is usually lacking is the processor (forget about the bluetooth). Does this processor really add any extra credit in taking photos?

Comment: Price range not to exceed 80D's, the feature is as I mentioned in the question I would like to take better pics of little creatures. It should not look like more blur if they move suddenly. The confusion here is there are few points which 77D is good but there are few points that favors 80D also. So as my requirement can I go with 77D as it costs lower that 80D?

Comment: A camera is basically just a box with sensor, camera mount, storage, and electronics to make it work together.  Since you have a specific photographic objective, you should determine which lenses will be suitable.

Comment: Hmm, does those sensors make any difference in captured image quality? I mean there are lot of other factors like ISO, shutter speed and others? Because in 80D shutter speed is higher, if I take a pic of a small bird can I get a clear picture in 77D with 1/4000 shutter speed? or only 80D can do it

Comment: I think this is a good question. Basically, you want to buy a camera for nature photography - fast-moving animals. You've narrowed down your options to the 77D or 80D. You are confused what camera features are more necessary/valuable for this kind of photography, and whether both (or even one) of these cameras has those features.

Comment: @Osullic that's correct, I am confused if 77D will do it or 80D only can do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

Comment: The 80D is a better sports/action camera, but not because it can shoot at 1/8000 and the 77D can not. It's because of the higher frame rate that allows frames to be taken more rapidly. To a lesser extent it is also the larger, brighter viewfinder that lets you see your subject a bit better. Can you get great action shots with either camera? Of course you can. With the advantage of the 80D, though, you'll likely be able to get more of them more easily.

Comment: @MichaelC Does frame rate matters in taking photos?

Comment: When taking sports action photos of birds in flight and similar subjects it sometimes can make a difference between getting the shot you wish and not. It's certainly not a be all/end all, but there is a 16.7% difference between 6 fps and 7fps. The 80D is also more resistant to natural elements (rain, dust, etc.) that are typically involved in taking such photos. In the end, *you* need to weigh all of the factors and decide what is more important to *you*. If I were in your shoes, I'd probably take the 80D over the 77D. That doesn't mean it is or is not the right choice for *you*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is an objective answer to this. Look at each camera's spec and try to figure out which features are essential.

Do you need weather sealing? Then 80D it is.
Do you need 7 fps? Then 80D it is.

I have no doubt you can get great images of moving small animals with a 77D.
1/4000 second is a very short time. If you need very short depth of field in bright conditions, you might need one step lower exposure, but for a hobby photographer, I would not expect that will be a limiting factor.

I doubt you do, so I say, go get the cheaper one, and spend the savings on a good lens.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the specs, very similar cameras. Roughly, the 80D is better overall quality (weather sealed, pentaprism viewfinder and much better battery life) but the 77D is lighter and slightly more advanced technologically (more recent image processor and Bluetooth).

I had to make a similar choice not so long ago (760D vs 70D) and I went for the heavier model, but the price difference was somewhat less.

If it's your first I would go for the 77D.

Comment: Why heavier build is preferred?

Comment: I didn't pick it up for the weight obviously:) Criteria were viewfinder, burst rate, and ruggedness.

Comment: Agreed. I had to decide between the 700/750D and the 70D. Almost went with the 700D due to the much cheaper price, but I don't regret a second of my decision to go with the 70D instead. It's my first DSLR too but especially if you want to shoot moving (or flying) subjects, the higher burst rate (and amount of burst images) really comes in handy. I've also had both in hands and just from the build, I'd pick the 70D too, but that's personal preference. To me, I like having something heavy in my hands with a sturdy grip.

Comment: @confetti 70d and 700d have more differences, in such cases I would also choose 70d. But with 77d and 80d the difference is too narrow that I can't identify the right one as I am not expert in this. I think I can go with 77d.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Something that's barely ever mentioned on comparison websites is that the 77D has a mode to switch from the regular canon UI to a more beginner friendly UI. I don't know if you'd ever use that but, given it'll be your first DSLR, maybe that's something you want to consider too! [This](https://cameradecision.com/compare/Canon-EOS-77D-vs-Canon-EOS-80D) is a very good comparison site, look it through carefully and decide what you will need. For example, a headphone port (only on 80D) would be useful if you do a lot of video.

Comment: @confetti the same comparison site made me think more about choosing either of them. Because the features which are specified in the difference I am not sure how much they differ in action! I won't do a lot of videos so video option is not in my bucket. If I can capture normal running animals or a bird as I mentioned in the question can I do it in 77d? That's what I am confused with. And if I do capture videos with 77d is there any compromisation with the audio quality recorded?

Comment: @confetti and the processor, does it make any difference in taking photos?

Comment: @Bharadwaj There shouldn't be any difference in audio quality. If you want good audio, get an external mic. Both cameras support that. The 77D will be fast enough for animal action, 1/4000 really is enough to freeze motion. If you do want that extra burst speed though, the 80D might make more sense. AFAIK the processor has nothing to do with image quality, but I **think** that if you shoot JPG+RAW, a better CPU makes a faster burst rate. Just an assumption though.